# Compare two CSV files in Powershell, indicating in which lines and columns mismatches occur

Tags: powershell, csv

I need to write a PowerShell script that tells me the line numbers and the columns that are different between two CSV files.  My script below only tells me if there is a difference in the line but does not tell me what exact column within the CSV is wrong.

```powershell
cls
$file = "C:\test\compare xls\1930_CoB_Birth_Records.csv"
$file2 = "C:\test\compare xls\1930_cob_jbnj.csv"
$linecount = 0

Get-Content $file |  ForEach-Object {
    $linecount++
    $line2Count = 0
    $a = $_
    Get-Content $file2 | ForEach-Object {
        $line2count++
        $errorCountLine = 0
        if ($line2count -eq $linecount) {
            $b = $_
            $errorCountLine += (@(Compare-Object $a $b -SyncWindow 0).count / 2)
            if ($errorCountLine -ne 0) {
                  Write-Host $line2Count "-" $errorCountLine
            } else {
                Write-Host "good"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the [`Compare-Object`](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/bdc20eac-bff6-44bc-b130-1a986c79fb78(v=wps.630).aspx) cmdlet (after importing each CSV file into its own object)?

Comment: i did.  too many columns so it wouldn't display all of them at once.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming both of your CSVs have the same number of records and also the same fields, something like this might work:

```
$csv1 = Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\foo.csv'
$csv2 = Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\bar.csv'

for ($line=1; $line -le $csv1.Length; $line++) {
  $a = @{};
  $b = @{};

  $csv1[$line-1].PSObject.Properties | % { $a[$_.Name] = $_.Value }
  $csv2[$line-1].PSObject.Properties | % { $b[$_.Name] = $_.Value }

  if (Compare-Object $a.Values $b.Values) {
    $mismatches = ($a.Keys | ? { $a[$_] -ne $b[$_] }) -join ', '
    "Line {0}: mismatch in column(s) {1}." -f $line, $mismatches
  }
}
```